# Maven Project with JSTL 1.2 shows JasperException

Tags: maven, jsp, jstl

I have tried with different JSTL dependencies in the pom.xml but the compiler gives JasperException.

I gives an JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

How to resolve this dependency issue with JSTL.

```
pom.xml:
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    (I have also tried with <groupId>jstl</groupId>)



web.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  
    </web-app> 


index.jsp:
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>
   <h2>Hello World!</h2>
   <c:out value="${'Welcome to JSTL'} "/>   
   <c:out value="${'This is JSTL Example'}" escapeXml="false"/>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?